# Error message in Pycharm running geopandas module. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, pycharm, geopandas

I get this error message:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

when running this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# File path
fp = r"data/Corine2012_Uusimaa.shp"
data = gpd.read_file(fp)
```

I have Python 3.6 installed and geopandas 0.3.0 for various versions of python. Geopandas was installed using: `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`. I am using PyCharm Community 2018.1.2

When I run this using Spyder at home it is fine. Any ideas on how to fix this? I had a search for the error codes online, but didn't find anything that matched.